Multiple git repo management and maintenance scheme for library development with multiple modules
We are developing a library (MyLib) which includes two modules, say Module_1 and Module_2.
The folder structure is as follows.
            MyLib
              |
        ---------------
        |              |    
       Module_1    Module_2  

There is a manager who is responsible for the release and version control of MyLib. Two independent teams are developing the two modules. Module_1 depends on Module_2 and vice versa.
We would like to maintain independent version controls for MyLib, Module_1, and Module_2.
We can maintain a git repo on MyLib so that the Manager can have version control on MyLib. An ideal configuration we can think of is as follows.
                 MyLib 
                   |
    ----------------------------
    |              |           | 
   Module_1    Module_2      .git
    |              |
   .git           .git  

Now, how to configure the independent git modules for Module_1 and Module_2 so that each team can independently go back to any previous versions?
For example, the team developing Module_1 will be using a particular version of  Module_2 and they should be able to go back to this particular version of Module_1  and  Module_2 from its git repo at any future date.
I found that including a Folder outside the git repo is not straightforward.
For me, our situation is a common scenario for any library which has multiple modules developed by independent teams and have dependency on each other modules.
Can somebody throw light on handling this type of scenario?
I checked git submodules. But I don't think it is the right choice for our use case.

A solution could be to have this folder structure
MyLib
    \Module_1
    \Module_2
    \setup

You would have a git repo for MyLib, another one for Module_1 and another one for Module_2.
setup will contain a map between modules and commit hashes, so it would contain a file like this:
cd Module_1
git checkout <some commit hash>
cd ../Module_2
git checkout <some other commit hash>

So, if there are separate desirable configurations for the different Modules for your different teams, have them the appropriate setup and run it as a bash script so members of a team will be on the same page.


Now, how to configure the independent git modules for Module_1 and Module_2 so that each team can independently go back to any previous versions?

There is nothing special to configure in git for this. It is pretty fitting for version control as you can always checkout any other version, which naturally includes previous ones.

I checked git submodules. But I don't think it is the right choice for our use case.

Then not. Git is distributed version control, you don't need to make use of submodules for it to work. You can have just as many repositories as you feel able to manage and until you reach your capacity.

Here is where I think most of your problem lies:

Module_1 depends on Module_2 and vice versa.

You have two modules that depend on each other, but at the same time you wish for them to be independent.

We would like to maintain independent version controls for MyLib, Module_1, and Module_2.

Even if we leave aside the fact that you wish for them to be two independent repositories, the problem still exists. You still have two projects with a circular dependency. As soon as one of the two introduces a change that affects the other one, the other project must be updated too, which in turn can trigger a change in the first project, and so on.
You would always be in a situation where each module needs "to chase" the modifications introduced by the other one, which might even be just a consequence of a change introduced by the first module itself.
A scenario like this can never grant true independence.
In my opinion, your best solution would be to re-design the two modules and understand where the core of your services should be (module1, module2, or even in a third module module3). Like so, the core module (whichever module would be) would become a true dependency, breaking the cycle, and making each module independent.
At this point, each project could effectively become an independent repository (module1, module2, [module3,] MyLib), where with the use of submodules, you could reconstruct the tree of dependencies and have all the different teams work on their respective project.
MyLib
  |
  |____ Module1 (submodule)
  |        |
  |        |_____ Module3 (submodule)
  |
  |
  |____ Module2 (submodule)
           |
           |____ Module3 (submodule)

